# How to select more than one point on a path?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, selections, anchor-point

I used the brush tool to draw a hand. I now want to resize the little finger:

[image]

I can see the individual points if I select the path:

[image]

When I click on a point with Direct Selection tool I can edit that point.

[image]

What I can't figure out is how to select multiple points and move them as a unit.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

While using the Direct Selection tool, you can drag a box around multiple points to select them. Or, or use the standard shortcut for multi-select (SHIFT key to add or subtract from the selection). The selected points (and their segments) will move together when you drag or use the keyboard arrow keys to move them.

This is part of the basics of vector editing in Illustrator. You might want to check the online Help or documentation, you'll get a lot more out of working with vectors in just a little while of reading or watching online tutorials.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I drag the DS tool, or lassoo tool, it just selects the entire path - not the areas I dragged over. Could I have locked all the points together somehow?

Comment: I don't see that. Even if the shape is not selected, when I drag around part of a shape with the Direct Selection tool, I select only the anchor points that were enclosed in the selection box. Is it possible the layer is locked, or that the shape is not a regular vector object, or has a clipping mast or some other modification? I'm not an expert on live shapes and some of the other Illustrator enhancements to regular vector objects.

Comment: The layer isn't locked. I'm definitely dragging a selection with the DS tool. I was actually able to drag over a selection in outline mode. Maybe it's because the object was drawn with a brush?

Comment: @ovokuro your usingthe white arrow?

Comment: @joojaa Yes. I drew the path with the brush tool. The points are not grouped, the layer isn't locked. It does let me select multiple points in outline mode though.

Comment: @ovokuro aaa.. yes. There is a trick. You need to actually start drawing your marqee  selection from outside your object.

Answer (score 0):

It's the lasso selection tool. That's the key. Circle the points you want, then command to move those points together.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the direct select tool and shift-click all the points you want (the selected nodes will become a solid color, instead of white inside), or use the lasso selection tool if that's your preference.

Please keep in mind that if you have selected points, you will *always* need to use the *direct selection tool* to manipulate them (shortcut "A" on your keyboard, or the white cursor in your menu). If you switch over to any other tools, like your standard *selection tool* (same icon, but it is "V" on the keyboard and is a hollow-looking cursor), it will default back to selecting and manipulating the entire object or path that your direct selection was from.

This may be where you are having difficulties. You should be able to simply direct select your points and (assuming you didn't use the lasso to get your points) be able to drag and move the chosen points without swapping to any other tools.